# Testing the value of Fields stored on Taxonomy Terms

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms, entities

I have a field (called Division) attached to a node. I want to print out a link (called Switch) on page.tpl.php that varies according to the value of this (node-based) field.

I can successfully do this with the following code:

In *template.php*

```
function elite_field_division_helper(&$variables) {
  if ($node = $variables['node']) {
    $field_division = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_division');
    if ($field_division[0]['tid'] == 1) {
      $variables['switch_site'] = '<a id="switch_site" href="'.$GLOBALS['base_url'].'/business'.'">Visit Our Business Website</a>';
    }
    else if ($field_division[0]['tid'] == 2) {
         $variables['switch_site'] = '<a id="switch_site" href="'.$GLOBALS['base_url'].'/home'.'">Visit Our At Home Website</a>';
    }
  }

}
```

In *page.tpl.php*

```
<?php if (!empty($switch_site)):?>
  <?php print $switch_site; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My question is: How can I get this code to work with fields that are attached to TAXONOMY PAGES? (As Drupal 7 allows taxonomy pages to have fields).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will help you: http://pixeljets.com/blog/writing-robust-code-uses-fields-drupal-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) is very good for overriding Taxonomy pages. You can have different page and layout variants per vocabulary, user, theme, site etc. You can then include your code in a custom panel pane for taxonomy pages, together with whatever layout or views necessary, or write your own CTools content type for Panels.